# If $\sum a_n$ is a convergent series of real numbers then the following series are convergent.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

If $\sum a_n$ is a convergent series of real numbers prove that the series:

1) $\sum a_n e^{-nx}$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,\infty)$;

2) $\sum \frac{a_n}{n^x}$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$.

My Try: 1) Let $v_n = e^{-nx}$. For each $x \in [0,\infty)$, the sequence $v_n$ is monotonic and for all $x \in [0,\infty)$, $|v_n(x)| = \frac{1}{e^{nx}} \leq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

And $\sum a_n$ is a convergent series of real numbers. Thus by Abel's Test we have  $\sum a_n e^{-nx}$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,\infty)$.

Similar conditions holds for 2. Is the proof correct??

Comment: A direct comparison would be quicker. Note that if $y\geq1$, then $\left|\frac{a_n}{y}\right|\leq |a_n|$

Comment: @TerraHyde We don't know $\sum |a_n| < \infty$

Comment: It looks to me like you proof is correct. Not sure why you have $[0,1]$ instead of $[0,\infty)$ in 2).

Comment: @zhw Hmm...that is a good point. Abel is the best choice after all. Sorry for my silliness.