# $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx = \sum \int_a^b f_n(x)g(x)dx.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $\sum f_n(x) $ be uniformly convergent to $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ where each $f_n$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. If $g: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be integrable on $[a,b]$, then $$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx = \sum \int_a^b f_n(x)g(x)dx.$$

we know that if $\sum f_n(x) $ be uniformly convergent implies $$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \sum \int_a^b f_n(x)dx.$$

If we can show that $\sum f_n(x)g(x)$ is uniformly convergent to $f(x)g(x)$.
But how to proceed? will integration by parts help out here??

Comment: Hint: the sum of a series is the limit of partial sums. What could you say if the sum on the right hand side was truncated to N?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $g$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then it is bounded.  Thus, there exists a number $B>0$ such that $|g(x)|\le B$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.  Now, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_a^b \left(g(x)\sum_{n}^N\,f_n(x)-g(x)f(x)\right)dx\right|&\le\int_a^b \left|g(x)\sum_{n}^N\,f_n(x)-g(x)f(x)\right|dx\\\\
&=\int_a^b \,|g(x)|\,\left|\sum_{n}^N\,f_n(x)-f(x)\right|dx\\\\
&\le B\int_a^b \left|\sum_{n}^N\,f_n(x)-f(x)\right|dx
\end{align}$$

Since the series $\sum_{n}f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f$, then for any given $\epsilon>0$ we can find a number $N'$ such that $\int_a^b \left|\sum_{n}^N\,f_n(x)-f(x)\right|dx <\frac{\epsilon}{B}$  whenever $N>N'$ .

And we are done!

Comment: I just thought about that fact.... integrable imples bounded

Comment: @user8795 Well done!  You probably would have gotten this then.

Comment: yeah.... thank you for a detailed answer!!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365162/if-sum-a-n-is-a-convergent-series-of-real-numbers-then-the-following-series-a

Comment: can you please help in the above link?

Comment: @user8795 I'll have a look.

Comment: Why does integrable imply bounded? $f(x)=(x-a)^{-1/2}$ is integrable and unbounded.

Comment: @bartgol That function is not Riemann integrable.  However, its improper integral exists.

Comment: @bartgol Why the down vote??

Comment: It did not mention in the question that the integrals were in the Riemann sense. The tag 'real-analysis' made me think about Lebesgue integral. And in that setting, integrable does not imply bounded.

Comment: @bartgol It doesn't say this. But I suspect that it is the case because (i) the OP seems to be compelled to show UC and (ii) Lebesgue theory would only require dominated convergence to interchange the operations, not UC. For a proof of this level, it would be surprising if Lebesgue integration was presumed. Does any of that sound reasonable?

Comment: Sure, I understand your point. And now I also suspect that that is the case, although it would still be a good exercise to prove it in the Lebesgue setting (even without dominated convergence).

Anyhow, it won't let me take the downvote away now, for some reason. It says my vote is locked. Sorry.

Comment: @bartgol I can edit and then you could remove. Fair?

Comment: "You last voted on this answer Jul 18 at 5:07. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Comment: @bartgol I just edited.

Comment: @bartgol Thank you very much!  I am recovering at home from surgery 3 weeks ago.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26130/discussion-between-bartgol-and-dr-mv).

Answer (score 1):

A complement about uniform convergence, too long to be in comment :

Notice that $\sum f_n(x) g(x)$ is not necessarily uniformly convergent if $g$ is only $L^1$.

Indeed, take ( on $[0,1]$ for simplicity) a serie of function that converge uniformly to $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and that verify $\forall n, \ \forall x \in [0,\frac{1}{2^n} ],\ f_n( x ) = 0$.

It's indeed possible to construct such a sequence by reccurence, defining :

$f_0(x) = \sqrt{ x}$ on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ and linear on $[\frac{1}{2^2} ,\frac{1}{2}]$ such that its continuous

$f_n(x) = \sqrt{x} - \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} f_k(x)$ on $[\frac{1}{2^n} , 1]$ and linear on  $[\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} ,\frac{1}{2^n}]$ such that its continuous

And you can verify that $\sum_n f_n$ converge uniformly to $\sqrt{x}$

Now take $g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ (and 0 if x=0). It's in $L^1$, and $f(x) g(x) = \mathbb{1}_{]0,1]}$

But as $f_n = 0$ on $[0,\frac{1}{2^n}]$ for any n, you have that

$$\| f(x)g(x) - \sum_{k=1}^n f_n(x)g(x) \|_{\infty} \geq \sup_{x\in [0,\frac{1}{2^n}]} | f(x)g(x) - \sum_{k=1}^n f_n(x)g(x) | \geq 1$$

So there is no uniform convergence

Comment: The problem here is that $g(x)$ is not Riemann integrable even though the improper integral $\int_0^1g(x)dx$ exists.

Comment: @Dr.MV Where does it say that g is Riemann integrable? I just see integrable

Comment: It doesn't say this.  But I suspect that it is the case because (i) the OP seems to be compelled to show UC and (ii) Lebesgue theory would only require dominated convergence to interchange the operations, not UC.  For a proof of this level, it would be surprising if Lebesgue integration was presumed.  Does any of that sound reasonable?